# Rユーザがpython を使いはじめる時に役立つサイトを教えてください。

Tags: python, r

Rユーザが、python を使いはじめていますが、戸惑うことが多いです。そういったRユーザのための比較対象表などが乗っているよいサイトを教えてください。できるだけ新しいものか、よくアップデートされているのがよいです。

Comment: 一部の誤字の修正を行いました。

Comment: @heliac2001 コメントではなく回答として頂けると他のユーザの参考になると思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 質問にクローズ票を投じます。オフトピックである理由: [どんな質問がリスト質問？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1382/3054) にて示されている「リスト質問」にあたります。実際に「自己宣伝（またはステマ) やリンクだけの回答が多くなりがち」という現象が見られます。

Answer (score 2):

ご質問の主旨は、PythonでRでやっていたことをやりたいということでしょうか?
私はRはほとんど使ったことがないのですが、Pythonでデータ解析用にRの代わりになるパッケージとしてはPandasが有名だと聞いています。

英語ですが、以下の公式サイトが参考になる思います。

[RとPandasの比較](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html)

日本語でも、"Pandas R 比較" とかで検索すれば色々と出てくると思います。

Answer (score 2):

このあたりとかどうでしょうか。

Python for R Users
http://www.slideshare.net/ajayohri/python-for-r-users

NumPy for R (and S-Plus) users – Mathesaurus
http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/r-numpy.html

このタイトルの「python for R users」とか「numpy for R users」とかで検索すると、他にも似たようなサイトが引っかかるようです。（すでに検索されていればすみません）

Answer (score 2):

Rのデータフレームと同じ感覚で使えるPandasから入ってみるのが良いと思います。

- [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org)
- [データ分析ライブラリPandasの使い方](http://librabuch.jp/2013/12/pandas_python_advent_calendar_2013/)

Answer (score 1):

関数の比較表を求めるよりも、Python から R を利用したほうが良いのではないでしょうか？

[参照１](http://qiita.com/ynakayama/items/f84dc659f1337d71dd9e) / [参照２](http://www.slideshare.net/gepuro/rpython) / [参照３](http://www.okada.jp.org/RWiki/?Python%20%A4%C7%A1%A1R)

Answer (score 1):

英語ですが、こんなページがありました。

[Python as a statistics workbench](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1595/python-as-a-statistics-workbench)

それに、このような本もあるようなので参考にしてはいかがでしょうか
[Pythonによるデータ分析入門――NumPy、pandasを使ったデータ処理](http://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873116556/)

Answer (score 1):

サイトではなく書籍で失礼致します。

他にも回答している方がいらっしゃいますが、一番メジャーなのは
[Pythonによるデータ分析入門――NumPy、pandasを使ったデータ処理](http://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873116556/)
でしょうか。Rとの比較は載っていませんが。

[データ分析プロセス (シリーズ Useful R 2)](http://www.kyoritsu-pub.co.jp/bookdetail/9784320123656)
はPython、R両方のコードがサポートでついてくるのでRとの比較という点ではおすすめです。

[入門 Python 3](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873117386/)
はデータ分析に焦点を当てておりませんが、他の本よりわかりやすく、またページ数が多く一通りのことは載っているのでPython初心者におすすめです。
結局前処理のことなどを考えるとプログラミングの必要がどうしても出てくるので。

Answer (score -2):

はじめまして、プロスタ編集部です。

質問者様のPython学習にお役に立ちたいと思い、おすすめのチュートリアルを紹介します。
(参考サイト：【Pythonの本・参考書の評判
】[http://programming-study.com/language/python-books/])

下記の5冊がPythonの学習にはおすすめです。ご参考になれば幸いです。

1.みんなのPython 第3版
2.Pythonスタートブック
3. 初めてのPython 第3版
4. Python入門[2&3対応]
5. パーフェクトPython (PERFECT SERIES 5)